# Select tables from DB using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the below code to display a list of all tables in my database.

```
$table_count = mysql_query("
    SELECT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_schema = 'DB_NAME'
"); 
$tables = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($table_count))
{
    $table = $row["TABLE_NAME"];
}
```

Is it possible to change this query to show all tables EXCEPT some?

If so can someone explain/show me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. You can either select some columns

```
SELECT foo, bar, baz from ...
```

or you specify where not by chaining your conditions with `AND` or `OR`

```
$table_count = mysql_query("
SELECT TABLE_NAME AS tableName, another_complicated_column as niceName 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'DB_NAME' 
AND another_column NOT LIKE 'FOOBARBAZ' 
AND another_another_column != 333
");
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you. I dont know if I need to ask this as another question but is it possible to show the table names "nicer"? EG instead of `client_info` show `Client Information`

Comment: Yes, just use `as` keyword. Not sure if you are allowed spaces though

Comment: Well, yes you can do this, though you shouldn't use whitespaces. Whitespaces will make handling the data really hard, and I'm not really sure if you can use them either way. I would go with camelCase or lodash only @user3092953

Comment: I've edited it in my answer in the second select block to show you how to give an alias to a column with `AS`

Comment: Thank you, great help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you change your query, you could filter out tables by name, for example:

```
$table_count = mysql_query(
"SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'DB_NAME' AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'TMP_%' "
);
```

This would filter out tables that begin with `TMP_`, leaving all others.